# How do I reduce a variable's length to 20 characters in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

Basically I have some very long variables and need only the first few characters.

I tried using this regex, but it doesn't work.

```
$var =~ s/(^.{20})?/$1/g;
```

It doesn't do anything to it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what kind of logic to you expect? ex: take first 5 characters only, then append a number if there are duplicates (regardless of variable scope)?

Comment: What in the world would make you think that regex substitution does anything at all?

Comment: That code matches first 20 characters... and then puts them right back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
$var = substr($var,0,20);
```

Note that the simpler:

```
substr($var,20) = '';
```

will croak if the string is less than 20 characters.

Or using substitution (assuming 5.10+):

```
$var =~ s/^.{20}\K.+//s;
```

Or using unpack:

```
$var = unpack 'a20', $var;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
substr($var, 20) = "";
```

deletes characters beyond position 20 in `$var`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the substitution you probably had in mind:

```
$var =~ s/^(.{20}).*/$1/;
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `.+`, because there's no point matching strings with exactly 20 characters.  But the `substr` is a better solution.

Comment: microscopically better with `.+` instead.  also, maybe /s is wanted.

Comment: If the string is less than 20 long, `substr` will issue a warning (with `use warnings` enabled). If this validation has been performed, I agree `substr` is better. I was merely trying to show the OP how it can be achieved with `s///`.

Comment: @toolic: no, getting a substr entirely out of range of the string warns; trying to set one dies.

Comment: You're right.  I saw the (W) and I presumed it was just a warning.

Comment: I didn't know about the substr function before, which is why I was using a regex. I wasn't too sure how to structure the regex, which is why it looks stupid, but thanks for your guys' help.